# VSTS Solution build fails on classic ASP.NET

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a large visual studio solution using multiple NUGET packages and multiple projects to build an asp.net web project. When I build locally using VS 2017, the build works correctly. I have an on-premise TFS 2014 server (soon to be retired) and use it to build the solution successfully using my TFS build server. I moved the source code to a VSTS project and defined a locally hosted build pipeline using the same build server that I use for TFS 2014. I have used this same build server with other VSTS project pipelines successfully.

My web project builds all the projects correctly (I can see it in the log and looking on my build server, I can see all the dlls in the c:\Agent_work\n\a directory including packages (from the built projects) or the built projects. The final project to build is the web project. It fails to find the other projects needed to build this final project.

I find this curious since some of the other projects in the solution have dependencies to other projects in the solution and build correctly. I have examined the web project .csproj file and the .sln file, and I see no issues in the references to these dependent projects.

Comment: There is no such thing as TFS 2014. Do you mean 2013, or 2015?

Comment: Please share your exact error description

Comment: Make sure you don't have any bin folders checked in and make sure the build steps clean the working directory at the beginning, sounds like you have some dlls checked in built already.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by switching the pipeline step from visual studio build to msbuild.